# Populating array elements with lists

Tags: python, arrays

I have following array:
    `b=np.zeros((5,5)).astype('int32')`

I wish to populate each element of above array with a list using below two arrays:
    `x=np.linspace(11, 15, 5)`

```
`y=np.linspace(6, 10, 5)`
```

The output i am looking at:

```
`array([[11,6], [11,7], [11,8], [11,9], [11,10]],
       [[12,6], [12,7], [12,8], [12,9], [12,10]],
       [[13,6], [13,7], [13,8], [13,9], [13,10]],
       [[14,6], [14,7], [14,8], [14,9], [14,10]],
       [[15,6], [15,7], [15,8], [15,9], [15,10]])`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @DocDriven said, you'll have to adjust the shape of the `b` array first, to `(5, 5, 2)`.

After that, note that you can set a whole row of `y` values by doing `b[row,:,1] = y` and a whole column of `x` values by doing `b[:,col,0] = x`.

Numpy also broadcasts shapes, which means you can use a 1d array to fill a 2d array; `b[:,:,1] = y` will fill all the `y` values in a single operation, while `b[:,:,0] = x.reshape((5, 1))` will do the same for the `x` values.

In short, you can get what you want by doing just:

```
b = np.zeros((5, 5, 2)).astype('int32')
b[:,:,1] = y
b[:,:,0] = x.reshape((5, 1))
```

Another way is to use `np.meshgrid()`:

```
b = np.array(np.meshgrid(x, y)).T.astype('int32')
```

Answer (score 0):

I slightly adjusted your original numpy array because you cannot replace a single integer with a sequence.

```
import numpy as np

b = np.zeros((5,5,2)).astype('int32')
x = np.linspace(11, 15, 5).astype('int32')
y = np.linspace(6, 10, 5).astype('int32')

idx_x = 0
idx_y = 0

for row in b:
    for _ in row:
        b[idx_x, idx_y] = [x[idx_x], y[idx_y]]
        idx_y += 1
    idx_y = 0
    idx_x += 1

print(b.tolist())
```

Output:

```
[[[11, 6], [11, 7], [11, 8], [11, 9], [11, 10]], 
 [[12, 6], [12, 7], [12, 8], [12, 9], [12, 10]], 
 [[13, 6], [13, 7], [13, 8], [13, 9], [13, 10]], 
 [[14, 6], [14, 7], [14, 8], [14, 9], [14, 10]], 
 [[15, 6], [15, 7], [15, 8], [15, 9], [15, 10]]]
```

If you want to keep it as a numpy array, do not cast it via `tolist()`.